# Java Reflection: Get a Field's Value where the Field is of an Interface Type

Tags: java, reflection

Say, there is a class (**A**) which has a field (**myField**). The type of the field **myField** is an interface (**I**). Everything is public.

I need to invoke a method of the class which is a type of the **myField **. My code is the following:

```
 Field myField = getField(myClass, "fieldName");
 Class fieldClass = myField.getType(); // returns I

 try {
        Class[] params = {String.class};
        Method method = fieldClass.getMethod("methodName", params);

        Object[] paramsObj = {new String("input")};
        boolean result = (Boolean) method.invoke(WHAT_MUST_I_PUT_HERE, paramsObj);
} catch...
```

As you can see the problem is I can't do thing like:

```
WHAT_MUST_I_PUT_HERE = myField.getClass() // returns Field
```

Can somebody help me?

**EDIT**: I have tried to use

```
TargetClass o = (TargetClass) myField.get(myClass)
```

but caught the IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
    Class myClass = service.getClass();
    Field myField = getField(myClass, "fieldName");

    TargetClass target = null;
    try {
        target = (TargetClass) myField.get(service);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStatckTrace();
    }

    Class fieldClass = myField.getType();
    try {
        Class[] params = {String.class};
        Method myMethod = fieldClass.getMethod("methodName", params);

        String paramItem = new String("value");
        Object[] paramsObj = {paramItem};
        boolean result = (Boolean) myMethod.invoke(target, paramsObj);         
    } catch ...
```

Answer (score 7):

The first argument to the `invoke` method is simply the object on which to call the method.  So let's say you got a non-static method corresponding to `I.m(String)`.  You need an instance of `I` to invoke it on (since this is a non-static method).

Presumably you want to call the equivalent of `myField.m(input)` via reflection, hence you simply pass in `myField` as the first argument:

```
boolean result = (Boolean) method.invoke(myField, paramsObj);
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate answer. I'll try this.

Comment: That solution doesn't work. I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Comment: I think, the reason is that myField has a Field type

Comment: Yeah - I just noticed that you're calling a `getType()` method on your field.  What does that do, and why can't you/aren't you using `getClass()`?  In any case, you'll need to pass in *some* instance of `fieldClass` to the invoke call;  if this is different from the actual class of the field then you're probably looking up the wrong method.

Comment: Cause if I do myField.getClass() it returns Field (see Field myField). I need to use getType() for that line:  Method method = fieldClass.getMethod("methodName", params);

Comment: Well, as I can see I really need to get an object from the myField (myField's actual object). Do you know, how to do that?

Comment: @Dmitry: Let's go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1282191#1282191) to get this ironed out rather than leaving a long trail of comments.